# Chart is not displaying using google chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am using google charts to display a chart but it is not displaying a chart. I can see the json printed as well in the firbug console but still chart is not displaying. Below is my code

```
function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ipaddress+'/getSpecificFields',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData) {
                alert('success');
                if (!$.browser.msie) {
                    console.log(jsonData);

                }
                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                data.addColumn("string", "abc");
                data.addColumn("string", "cde");
                data.addColumn("string", "fgh");

                data.addRows(jsonData.length);

        var i = 0;
        $.each(jsonData, function () {

            data.setValue(i, 0, this.abc);
            data.setValue(i, 1, this.cde);
            data.setValue(i, 2, this.fgh);
            i++;
        });
                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, {
                    width: 400,
                    height: 240
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
                if (!$.browser.msie) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            }
        });
    }}
```

json which is returning from the server

```
[Object { abc="leave, cde="80%", fgh="52b83880a36dcda423000001"}, Object { abc="Meeting", cde="60%", fgh="52b83880a36dcda423000002"}, Object { abc="Work", cde="70%", fgh="52b83880a36dcda423000003"}]
```

from browser e.g localhost:3000/something

```
[
  {
    "abc": "Work",
   "cde": "50%",
    "ghe": "1",    
  },
  {    
    "cde": "50%",
    "abc": "Sick",
    "ghe": "2"
  },
  {
    "abc": "Some",
    "cde": "50%",
    "ghe": "3",    
  }
]
```

and server side code in node js

```
var jsonString = [];
var jsonParse;
test.find({abc:1,cde:1,ghe:1},function (err, list, count) {
        if (err) throw(err);
        list.forEach(function(listLoop){

            jsonParse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listLoop));
            console.log("jsonParse " + JSON.stringify(listLoop)); 
            jsonString.push(jsonParse);
        });        
        res.json(jsonString);
    });
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look valid, but that could just be the way your browser is displaying it.  In your browser, go to the URL specified by `ipaddress+'/getSpecificFields'` and update your post with the output from that so I can confirm whether or not the JSON is valid.

Comment: @asgallant, I have updated the post. you can verify the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to remove `jsonData` from the DataTable constructor:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

should be:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Second, your data is comprised entirely of strings, which a PieChart can't do anything with.  PieCharts require two columns of data: 1 string for the labels and 1 number for the values.  If you want to create a number column, make sure that your JSON does not put quotes around the numbers.

Third (and I assume this one is just a typo from changing your real data to sample data), you pull data from the `fgh` property of the objects in the data array, but you don't have an `fgh` property in the objects.

Comment: Thanks that number thing was an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't seem correct, you should check the Google docs here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

and this SO question which sounds like exactly what you are trying to do:

[Creating Google Pie Chart based on JSON data using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317138/creating-google-pie-chart-based-on-json-data-using-codeigniter)